What is the topology of a Clifford algebra?
I'm reading Hamilton's Mathematical Gauge Theory and I'm currently studying the Pin and Spin groups. Hamilton defines them as specific subsets of a Clifford algebra, and it is understood that the topology on the Pin and Spin groups is inherited from the Clifford algebra. My question is: what is the "usual" topology in a Clifford algebra? It is a finite-dimensional vector space, so is it any of the (equivalent) topologies induced by a norm?

I would be astounded if anybody ever used a different topology on the Clifford algebra (except maybe some algebraic geometers who could use the Zariski topology).

Quadradic forms have a symmetric bilinear form associated with them via the polarization identity which induces a norm. I'd assume the metric topology associated with that norm is a natural choice.

@CyclotomicField I'm also interested in the case in which the bilinear form is not positive-definite, in which case I believe there is no induced norm

For any finite-dimensional space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, there is a unique Hausdorff topology that makes it into a topological vector space and which coincides with the Euclidean topology.
